Provide Config.cmake for libraries using C++20 modules
I have a library written in C++20 modules.
I previously used this library in the form of add_subdirectory(../NeLib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/NeLib)
Now I hope that after I provide a NeLibConfig.cmake, other projects can use it directly through find_package
The project structure is:
NeLib
File.cppm
Image.cppm
... (Some other libraries,All are cppm files)
CMakeLists.txt
NeLibConfig.cmake.in
The content of the CMakeLists.txt file is：
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(NeLib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")
set(VERSION "1.0.0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_library(NeLib STATIC )

file(GLOB module_files "*.cppm")

configure_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/NeLibConfig.cmake.in"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/NeLibConfig.cmake"
    @ONLY
)
target_sources(NeLib
    PUBLIC
    FILE_SET cxx_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES
    ${module_files}
)

install(TARGETS  ${PROJECT_NAME}  DESTINATION /usr/lib EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME} FILE_SET cxx_modules)
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION /usr/lib/cmake/NeLib/)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/NeLibConfig.cmake"
        DESTINATION "${test_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/cmake/NeLib/")


The content of the NeLibConfig.cmake.in file is：
@PACKAGE_INIT@
set(NeLib_VERSION "1.0.0")
set(NeLib_SOVERSION "1.0")

find_library(NeLib_LIBRARIES
    NAMES libNeLib.a
    HINTS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(NeLib
    REQUIRED_VARS NeLib_LIBRARIES
    VERSION_VAR NeLib_VERSION
)

if(NeLib_FOUND)
    add_library(NeLib::NeLib INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(NeLib::NeLib PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}"
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "${NeLib_LIBRARIES}"
        INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "OpenCV::opencv_core"
    )
endif()


Then we install this library：

cd NeLib && mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -G Ninja -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++
cmake --build .
sudo cmake --install .

sudo cmake --install .command intercepts part of the information as follows:
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /usr/lib/libNeLib.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/lib/Image.cppm
-- Up-to-date: /usr/lib/cmake/NeLib/NeLib.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/lib/cmake/NeLib/NeLib-noconfig.cmake
-- Installing: /lib/cmake/NeLib/NeLibConfig.cmake

Use this library in a new project：
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(untitled)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
find_package(NeLib REQUIRED)
add_executable(untitled
    main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(untitled
    NeLib
)

main.cpp
import Image;

int main () {
    nl::Image image("../desk.png");
    image.show("show");
    return 0;
}

Compile error：
/opt/clion/bin/cmake/linux/x64/bin/cmake --build /home/yongheng/Projects/untitled/cmake-build-debug --target untitled -j 10
[3/4] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/clang++   -g -std=gnu++23 -fcolor-diagnostics -MD -MT CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o.d @CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o.modmap -o CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/yongheng/Projects/untitled/main.cpp
/home/yongheng/Projects/untitled/main.cpp:1:8: fatal error: module 'Image' not found
    1 | import Image;
      | ~~~~~~~^~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


As a rule: find_library, find_package_handle_standard_args are used only in Find scripts (Find<>.cmake). Config scripts (Config<>.cmake) do not use these functions.

Also, here are some off-topic notes: 1) Use the full project() signature (with version and language); there is no need for an additional VERSION variable. 2) CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER is a user-provided variable! Check CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID and restrict builds if u need a particular compiler. But a better way is to require the needed compiler features (rather than a particular compiler). 3) Never ever hardcode install prefix (like /usr/lib in the install() calls!) -- use CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and let a user decide where to install. 4) Read the tutorial on how to make a relocatable pkg

CMakeLists.txt to :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(NeLib)

# set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")
set(VERSION "1.0.0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_library(NeLib STATIC )

file(GLOB module_files "*.cppm")

configure_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/NeLibConfig.cmake.in"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/NeLibConfig.cmake"
    @ONLY
)
target_sources(NeLib
    PUBLIC
    FILE_SET cxx_modules TYPE CXX_MODULES FILES
    ${module_files}
)

target_compile_features(NeLib PUBLIC cxx_std_23)

install(TARGETS  ${PROJECT_NAME}  DESTINATION /usr/lib EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME} FILE_SET cxx_modules)
install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION /usr/lib/cmake/NeLib/)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/NeLibConfig.cmake"
        DESTINATION "${test_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/cmake/NeLib/")


NeLibConfig.cmake.in to:
@PACKAGE_INIT@
include ( "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/NeLib.cmake" )

